# How to call MYSQL native function CONVERT_TZ using Hibernate Creteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Is it possible to call the MYSQL `CONVERT_TZ(date,param1,param2)` using HIBERNATE/JPA.

I have a table which contains multiple column along with datetime for this query want to send param1 and param2 as dynamic parameter

```
SELECT
    *,
    dateTime as dateTime,
    CONVERT_TZ(dateTime,'ASIA/Calcutta','Europe/Helsinki') AS zonalDateTime
from travels
```

How can I acheive this using Hibernate criteria/JPA ?

Answer (score 2):

In JPQL you can use

```
SELECT 
  /* all other fields you need */
  function('CONVERT_TZ', dateTime,'ASIA/Calcutta','Europe/Helsinki') 
  FROM travels
```

More information on that topic:

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/

Comment: Same thing how I can achieve using Hibernate Criteria and other options of hibernate like criterion,restrictions etc.,